# showing undefined when accsessing array elemests after fetching data from an API

Tags: javascript, arrays, api, object

I was trying to access the codeforces API . Which Return value: Returns a list of User objects for requested handles.

Example: "https://codeforces.com/api/user.info?handles=tushar1_000;yogeshk972

I mad this function getData()

```
let output;
function getData(){
 const url = "https://codeforces.com/api/user.info?handles=tushar1_000;yogeshk972";
    fetch(url).then( (response)=>{
        return response.json();
    }).then( (data) =>{

          console.log(data)

    })
}
getData();
```

when i console it shows me an array ;
[image]

but whwn i try to accesess the 1st element of array it is showing me undefined .

```
function getData(){
 const url = "https://codeforces.com/api/user.info?handles=tushar1_000;yogeshk972";
    fetch(url).then( (response)=>{
        return response.json();
    }).then( (data) =>{

          
        console.log(data[0])
        
    })
}
getData();
```

[image]

can anybody tell me why is it showing undefined.

Comment: Can you post the result of `console.log(data)`

Comment: in both case i see undefined, are you sure it shows an array?

Comment: it's giving you back an object with `{ status: "ok", results: [...] }`. So you need to console `data.results[0]`

Comment: I have just tried your code and it's working just fine. Are there anything that you didn't show us? Are you by any chance assigning `data` to the variable `output` and logging `output` and that's why you get `undefined`?

Comment: that's everything in my code and it is giving me status:"ok" when i used the console.log(data) as it is giving me an array of size 2 so i thought to accsess it with data[0] but is showing undefined .

Comment: @ibrahimmahrir i am not assigning to output  . That ouutput variable i did not used anywhere in my code i just declared it .

Comment: @RinkeshGolwala sorry i posted the wrong picture now i have  edited it .

Answer (score 2):

After making your request to the API you recieved an array
with the name of `results`

You have to access it this way

`data.results[0]`

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

try now

```
function getData(){
 const url = "https://codeforces.com/api/user.info?handles=tushar1_000;yogeshk972";
    fetch(url).then( (response)=>{
        return response.json();
    }).then( (data) =>{

          
        console.log(data.result[0])
        
    })
}
getData();
```

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to access `index value` of an object instead of an array which is not possible. The data is an `object`.
`data.results` is an array, so indexing can work on it.

Answer (score 0):

The `data` variable is an **object**, not an **array**, and `0` is not a **property** of it.

To access an object with its a property you don't use `ìndex` like a normal array, but the name of the property.

To check the type of the `data` object :

`Array.isArray(data) // expected false`

You should know that Objects are *associative arrays*.

To access to `result` property, you can do one of these suggesstions :

```
data['result'][index] // result is the name of the property
data.result[index]
```